# Remove swipe to unlock curtain shield from Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME Shell

Tags: 19.04, gnome-shell, lock-screen, unlock

I think having the choice to disable this swipe to unlock (phone style) clock curtain as shown in the screenshot below is necessary.

[image: swipe to unlock ubuntu curtain]

Unfortunately, there is no such settings and the "[Disable Screen Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/)" extension doesn't work with this version of GNOME Shell.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to swipe away the curtain -- just start typing your password and the curtain will vanish.

Comment: No it doesn't: If your don't have password or the computer is not locked (simple suspend screen), you do need to drag it up or press ESC, as just moving the mouse leave you with this curtain shield. My computer is not a smartphone in my pocket, I should not have to unlock it.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME Shell, I found only one working GNOME Shell extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2245/remove-shield/

[image: remove shield extension]

Note: it does glitch slightly when waking up the screen: the shield briefly appears.

Comment: This extension (remove-shield) doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04, but it look like it's to useful anymore: the curtain is no more present

Comment: This is quite annoying for me - that curtain did not bother me at all (hitting spacebar or a mouse click/drag would instantly unlock) OTOH the slightest mouse movement will now unblank/unlock the desktop for another 10 minutes and when using some apps that prevent blank/lock the monitors now remain powered on until manually re-blanked! It's also very useful when switching between VT's as leaving a desktop unlocked on an unused VT for a long time makes gnome-shell fall behind on events and locks up for some time before resuming (can be several minutes in worst cases).